# d3 stratify - missing data field

Tags: d3.js, tree

I am using stratify to build a d3 tree from a flat data structure. However, some fields are missing when I try to call them with d.data.*fieldname*

Here is my data structure:

```
var flatData = [

  {"name": "Data Encrypted", "parent": null, "category": "test", "score": null },
  {"name": "Malware on Target", "parent": "Data Encrypted", "category": "test", "score": null  },
  {"name": "Malware executed", "parent": "Data Encrypted", "category": "test", "score": "1"  },
  {"name": "Files modified", "parent": "Data Encrypted", "category": "test", "score": "1"  },

];
```

I am building the hierarchical data structure with this stratify command:

```
var treeData = d3.stratify()
  .id(function(d) { return d.name; })
  .parentId(function(d) { return d.parent; })
  (flatData);
```

The d3 tree is displayed correctly, and I can expand / collapse nodes etc, and display the ID and Name of each node using d.data.id and d.data.name respectively. If I try and use d.data.score or d.data.category to display data I get an 'undefined' error.

Any information that can help me get past this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your question is unclear: `d.data.score` and `d.data.category` do work: https://jsfiddle.net/gm8o4g1r/

Comment: Apologies for not putting full code - I was convinced that the problem is with the stratify function. I have created a jfiddle that shows the issue - https://jsfiddle.net/shorgy/kkk63fkb/

Comment: in the above jfiddle, expand the tree nodes and click on a childless node - it should alert and display the d.data.score value but shows undefined.

Comment: In that case it is `d.data.data.score`.

Comment: Awesome - that indeed fixed it. Many thanks. I'd appreciate a basic explanation if possible purely as I have no idea what I did wrong and want to avoid repeats. No problem if you don't have time for this, and thanks again.